# can anybody suggest a faster alternative to this regex algorithm?

Tags: java, android, replace

I need to call this function pretty frequently. Basically, it replaces all accented characters by its unaccented equivalents, changes spaces to "_", converts to lowercase, and strips the rest of alien codes, so it is safe to use as filenames/url paths/etc.. The problem is, as you see, it looks terrible from the performance point of view. Can anybody think of a cleaner, faster alternative?

```
public static String makeValidPathName(String rawString) {
    if (rawString==null) return null;
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ÁÀÂÄáàäaàáâãäå]","a");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("æ","ae");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("çÇ","c");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ÈÉÊËèéêë]","e");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ìíîïÍÌÎÏ]","i");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("ñÑ","n");                            
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ÓÓÖÔòóôõö]","o");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("œ","oe");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ÙÚÛÜùúûü]", "u");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ýÿ]","y");
    rawString= rawString.replaceAll("[^a-z A-Z 0-9 \\_ \\+]","");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll(" ","_");
    return rawString.toLowerCase();
}
```

--- EDIT

Ok, guys ... I did the performance tests on all 4 cases:

- Case 1) The original routine as it is posted here.
- Case 2) The improvement suggested by @WChargin
- Case 3) The Lookup Table suggested by @devconsole with my optimizations for SparseArray
- Case 4) The Normalizer approach suggested by @Erik Pragt

And ... the winner is ... TADAAA .....

```
D/REPLACEMENT_TEST(18563): *** Running Tests (1000 iterations)
D/REPLACEMENT_TEST(18563): Original REGEX  : 13533 ms
D/REPLACEMENT_TEST(18563): Compiled REGEX  : 12563 ms
D/REPLACEMENT_TEST(18563): Character LUT   : 1840 ms
D/REPLACEMENT_TEST(18563): Java NORMALIZER : 2416 ms
```

- It's interesting the pattern compilation optimization doesn't help much.
- I see I was also completely wrong about my assumptions on the speed on REGEXES, and devconsole was right in his educated guess on Normalizer outperforming regexes.
- It is amazing how slow REGEXES are. Differences by an order of magnitude really surprise me. I will try to avoid them on Java.
- The lookup table is the fastest option by short margin. I'll stick with this solution, because w/ the Normalizer one, I'd still have to replace some chars by hand (spaces into "_"), then convert to lowercase.

The tests were done in a Samsung Galaxy Tab v1 10.1.

Please find attached the source code for the test cases.

```
public class Misc { 

    /* Test 2 (@WCChargin's Regex compilation) initialization */

static Map<Pattern, String> patterns = new HashMap<Pattern, String>();

static {
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("[ÁÀÂÄáàäaàáâãäå]") ,"a");
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("æ"),"ae");
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("çÇ"),"c");
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("[ÈÉÊËèéêë]"),"e");
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("[ìíîïÍÌÎÏ]"),"i");
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("ñÑ"),"n");                            
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("[ÓÓÖÔòóôõö]"),"o");
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("œ"),"oe");
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("[ÙÚÛÜùúûü]"), "u");
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("[ýÿ]"),"y");
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile("[^a-z A-Z 0-9 \\_ \\+]"),"");
        patterns.put(Pattern.compile(" "),"_");
}

    /* Test 3 (@devconsole's Lookup table) initialization */
static SparseArray<String> homeBrewPatterns=new SparseArray<String>();
/** helper function to fill the map where many different chars map to the same replacement */
static void fillMap(String chars, String replacement) { for (int i=0,len=chars.length(); i<len; i++) homeBrewPatterns.put(chars.charAt(i), replacement); }
static {
    // fill the sparsearray map with all possible substitutions: Any char code gets its equivalent, ie, ä->a. a->a. A->a
    // this also does the toLowerCase automatically. If a char is not in the list, it is forbidden and we skip it.
    fillMap("ÁÀÂÄáàäaàáâãäå","a");
    fillMap("æ","ae");
    fillMap("çÇ","c");
    fillMap("ÈÉÊËèéêë","e");
    fillMap("ìíîïÍÌÎÏ","i");
    fillMap("ñÑ","n");
    fillMap("ÓÓÖÔòóôõö","o");
    fillMap("œ","oe");
    fillMap("ÙÚÛÜùúûü","u");
    fillMap("ýÿ","y");
    fillMap(" ","_");
    for (char c='a'; c<='z'; c++) fillMap(""+c,""+c); // fill standard ASCII lowercase -> same letter 
    for (char c='A'; c<='Z'; c++) fillMap(""+c,(""+c).toLowerCase()); // fill standard ASCII uppercase -> uppercase
    for (char c='0'; c<='9'; c++) fillMap(""+c,""+c); // fill numbers
}

    /** FUNCTION TO TEST #1: Original function, no pattern compilation */ 
public static String makeValidPathName(String rawString) {
    if (rawString==null) return null;
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ÁÀÂÄáàäaàáâãäå]","a");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("æ","ae");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("çÇ","c");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ÈÉÊËèéêë]","e");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ìíîïÍÌÎÏ]","i");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("ñÑ","n");                            
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ÓÓÖÔòóôõö]","o");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("œ","oe");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ÙÚÛÜùúûü]", "u");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[ýÿ]","y");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("[^a-z A-Z 0-9 \\_ \\+]","");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll(" ","_");
    return rawString.toLowerCase();
}
/** FUNCTION TO TEST #2: @WCChargin's suggestion: Compile patterns then iterate a map */
public static String makeValidPathName_compiled(String rawString) {
    for (Map.Entry<Pattern, String> e : patterns.entrySet()) {
        rawString=e.getKey().matcher(rawString).replaceAll(e.getValue());
    }
    return rawString.toLowerCase();
}

    /** FUNCTION TO TEST #3: @devconsole's suggestion: Create a LUT with all equivalences then append to a stringbuilder */
public static String makeValidPathName_lut(String rawString) {
    StringBuilder purified=new StringBuilder(rawString.length()); // to avoid resizing
    String aux; // to avoid creating objects inside the for
    for (int i=0, len=rawString.length(); i<len; i++) {
        aux=homeBrewPatterns.get(rawString.charAt(i));
        if (aux!=null) purified.append(aux);
    }
    return purified.toString();
}

    /** FUNCTION TO TEST #4: @Erik Pragt's suggestion on the use of a Normalizer */
public static String makeValidPathName_normalizer(String rawString) {
        return rawString == null ? null
            : Normalizer.normalize(rawString, Form.NFD)
                .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}

    /** Test Runner as a Runnable, just do a Handler.post() to run it */

public static Runnable msStringReplacementTest=new Runnable() {

    public void run() {


    String XTAG="REPLACEMENT_TEST";

    Log.d(XTAG, "*** Running Tests");

    int ITERATIONS=1000;

    String[] holder=new String[4];

            /* http://www.adhesiontext.com/ to generate dummy long text ... its late n im tired :) */

    String tester="e arte nací valse ojales i demediada cesé entrañan domó reo ere fiaréis cinesiterapia fina pronto mensuraré la desatufases adulantes toree fusca ramiro hez apolíneo insalvable atas no enorme mí ojo trola chao fas eh borda no consignataria uno ges no arenque ahuyento y daca pío veló tenle baúl ve birria filo rho fui tañe mean taz raicita alimentarías ano defunciones u reabráis repase apreciaran cantorales ungidas naftalina ex guió abomba o escribimos consultarás des usó saudí mercó yod aborrecieses guiri lupia ña adosado jeringara fe cabalgadura tú descasar diseñe amar limarme escobero latamente e oreó lujuria niñez fabularios da inviernen vejé estañarán dictará sil mírales emoción zar claudiquéis ó e ti ñ veintén dañen ríase esmeraras acató noté as mancharlos avisen chocarnos divertidas y relata nuera usé fié élitro baba upa cu enhornan da toa hechizase genesíacos sol fija aplicó gafa pi enes fin asé deal rolar recurran cacen ha id pis pisó democristiano oes eras lañó ch pino fijad ñ quita hondazos ñ determinad vid corearan corrompimiento pamema meso fofas ocio eco amagados pian bañarla balan cuatrimestrales pijojo desmandara merecedor nu asimiladores denunciándote jada ñudos por descifraseis oré pelote ro botó tu sí mejorado compatibilizaciones enyerba oyeses atinado papa borbón pe dé ñora semis prosada luces leí aconteciesen doy colmará o ve te modismos virola garbillen apostabas abstenido ha bajá le osar cima ají adormecéis ñu mohecí orden abrogándote dan acanilladas uta emú ha emporcara manila arribeña hollejo ver puntead ijadeáis chalanesca pechugón silbo arabescos e i o arenar oxidas palear ce oca enmaderen niñez acude topó aguanieves i aconsejaseis lago él roía grafito ceñir jopo nitritos mofe botáis nato compresores ñu asilo amerizan allanándola cuela ó han ice puya alta lío son de sebo antieconómicas alá aceza latitud faca lavé colocándolos concebirlo miserea ñus gro mearé enchivarse";

    long time0=System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i=0; i<ITERATIONS; i++) holder[0]=makeValidPathName(tester); // store in an array to avoid possible JIT optimizations
    long elapsed0=System.currentTimeMillis()-time0;

    Log.d(XTAG, "Original REGEX  : "+elapsed0+" ms");

    long time1=System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i=0; i<ITERATIONS; i++) holder[1]=makeValidPathName_compiled(tester); // store in an array to avoid possible JIT optimizations
    long elapsed1=System.currentTimeMillis()-time1;

    Log.d(XTAG, "Compiled REGEX  : "+elapsed1+" ms");

    long time2=System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i=0; i<ITERATIONS; i++) holder[2]=makeValidPathName_lut(tester); // store in an array to avoid possible JIT optimizations
    long elapsed2=System.currentTimeMillis()-time2;

    Log.d(XTAG, "Character LUT   : "+elapsed2+" ms");

    long time3=System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i=0; i<ITERATIONS; i++) holder[3]=makeValidPathName_normalizer(tester); // store in an array to avoid possible JIT optimizations
    long elapsed3=System.currentTimeMillis()-time3;

    Log.d(XTAG, "Java NORMALIZER : "+elapsed3+" ms");

    Log.d(XTAG, "Output 0: "+holder[0]);
    Log.d(XTAG, "Output 1: "+holder[1]);
    Log.d(XTAG, "Output 2: "+holder[2]);
    Log.d(XTAG, "Output 3: "+holder[3]);
    }
};
```

Guys, thank you very much for your suggestions :) I love stackoverflow :)

Comment: Why not iterate over the characters of the string the old-fashioned way, look at each character exactly once, do a transformation (or skip the character) and append the result to a StringBuilder?

Comment: hmmm... frankly, I don't know... Do you think, for example, in case of a String with 300 chars and only one accent, this iteration would be faster than the Regex?

Comment: If you do benchmark, please try the solution from @devconsole. I imagine it will be faster, since you are using regex to pattern match when you really need to do a simple lookup for each character conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a static `Map<Character,String>` that maps a character to its replacement string, that is map 'Á' to "a", 'ä' to "a", etc. Also include one-to-one correspondencies, that is map 'a' to "a", and so forth. You get a map with a couple of hundred entries at most.

Now iterate over the characters of the input string and look for a replacement string in your static map. Skip the character if the map does not contain an entry, otherwise append the replacement to a StringBuilder.

Comment: This should be the fastest solution. +1

Comment: The Normalizer might do something like this internally so it is probably worth looking into (see other solution).

Comment: hmmmm.... interesting!! To be honest, i thought Regex could be natively implemented so any effort like this would not perform faster, but I see I'm probably wrong.... So in this fashion, instead of a Map, I could do it with a SparseArray<Char> , and map the charcode("ä") --int-- -> a ... it should be faster?

Comment: Yes, in an Android environment you can also use SparseArray<String> (not <Character>). It is probably faster since it does not require the char <-> Character boxing.

Comment: I'm gonna try this .... btw just looked at the Normalizer source code, it looks ultra complicated, I suppose it is because it does a lot of additional things, just by the hundreds of lines it doesn't look like it will be faster to solve a simple problem like mine... It looks better suited for very big texts, rather that repeatedly call it for short strings, but it's only an impression  ....

Comment: Please do the performance test on all three solutions -- my guess is the Normalizer solution will be a lot faster than the regex, plus it will cover a lot more edge cases (work for more languages) than a home brewed solution.

Comment: really? My guess is homebrew>regex>normalizer but I will definitely do the performance tests on the 3 situations! And you are right about the edge cases, that for sure..

Answer (score 2):

If you must use regex, you could precompile your patterns:

```
Map<Pattern, String> patterns = new HashMap<Pattern, String>();
{ // initializer block (you could do this in constructor also)
    patterns.put(Pattern.compile("[ÁÀÂÄáàäaàáâãäå]") ,"a");
    rawString = rawString.replaceAll("æ","ae");
    // etc.
}

// later...
for (Map.Entry<Pattern, String> e : patterns) {
    rawString = e.getValue().matcher(rawString).replaceAll(e.getKey());
}
```

The line in the `for` loop is the key. Here's the dissection:

- `e.getValue()` gets the pattern from the map key
- `.matcher(rawString)` gets a `Matcher` object for the pattern, to match instances of the regex to the given string (the raw string)
- `.replaceAll` works just like the `String` method (I believe `String` uses this, actually)
- `e.getKey()` gets the value to be replaced from the map key

---

**Links for further reading:**

- [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)  and its method [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this is what I need because Normalizer looks cool and standard, but I'd need to do some other substitutions by hand. Thanks for also submitting the code example!

Comment: Maybe a bit more compact but why should it be better performance-wise?

Comment: `replaceAll` calls `Pattern.compile` every time, for each regex. This calls it once (per regex).

Comment: Okay, but still this solution would have to iterate over the string n times where n is the number of entries in the map.

Comment: yes but I wonder if there¡s a solution that doesnt iterate N times... other than a satanic regex that does it all at once, that is well beyond my knowledge :S

Comment: Yes: the Big-O end behavior is the same, but the actual runtime would be less, and that's what matters.

Answer (score 1):

What you could try to do, instead of using Regular Expressions, is to use a [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html). You can find information about it [here](http://www.drillio.com/en/software-development/java/removing-accents-diacritics-in-any-language/).

From that page:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.text.Normalizer.Form;

// ...

public static String removeAccents(String text) {
    return text == null ? null
        : Normalizer.normalize(text, Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
}
```

It doesn't solve all your needs, but it works for quite an extensive range of characters. However, I would recommend doing a performance measurement anyway, to compare the two solutions. If you really want to go with the regex solution, try creating some static Patterns first and use Matchers after that, so you'll only get the overhead of creating those patterns once.

Comment: Oohh!! Looks like it's just what I'm looking for! Do you think it will perform better than the above?

Comment: :-). No problem. Well, that's why I suggested creating a benchmark first, if you are really concerned about the performance. I wouldn't be bothered to much about it, and writing a microbenchmark can be tricky.

Comment: Well I need to call this function in tight loops hundreds of times, in my case a benchmark will probably be worth... Anyway I'm going for the compiled-pattern solution because that way I can do all the substitutions at once, instead of combining the normalizer + regex. +1 for the normalizer thing, it will be handy in the future :)